# X axis error with ggplotly and facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to create a bar plots with ggplotly and facet_wrap. However, the x-axis looks weird for the second and third subplots. below is my code:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

setInfo<- data.frame(sampleNumber=rep(c("A","B","C"),4),
                     Category=rep(c("Class 1", "Class 2","Class 3"),4),
                     Value=rep(1,12))

setInfo %>% 
  ggplot(aes(sampleNumber,fill = sampleNumber))+
  geom_bar()+
  facet_wrap(~Category,nrow = 1,scales = "free_x")->plot_this

ggplotly(plot_this)
```

Comment: I think it's the same issue as this https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1221

Comment: Thanks so much! Seems to be the same problem

Comment: Following the link posted by @StupidWolf it seems to be a bug in (gg)plotly. Also, I tested with different random datasets. The specific issue seems to be related to the number of categories per panel. ggplotly with scales "free_x" breaks the axis in panels with only one category, except in the case that this happens to be the first panel, as in the example data provided by Qianshun.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed via PR [#1788](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/pull/1788).

As I figured out this issue was not related to the use of `scales="free_x"` but happened more generally when using a discrete axis with only one category present in panels > 1 (see my issue [#1720](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1720) and also [#1577](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1577)).

I have had a look on the issue and was able to come up with a solution to fix this via PR [#1788](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/pull/1788) which was merged on 2020-06-18.

After installing the latest devel version of plotly via `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")` your example should now be rendered correctly like so:

[image]